# Post to fan page as admin worked yesterday, not today

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page, fan-page

To post to facebook fan page, using a php script which is called by a cronjob, im using the following code, which worked yesterday while testing, it is no longer working.

```
include_once("../facebooksdk/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XX',
  'secret' => 'XX',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = 'XX';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/".$page_id."?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       => "Welcome to TuneHub!"
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/".$page_id."/feed","post",$args);
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

I cant figure out why it would work temporarily, then the following day when the code has been added to the live site, its no longer working (on the test or live site, it isnt working)

is there an API change that is killing the function?
or is there something I am doing wrong with the code that flagged Facebook to prevent it from posting?

(the code may have changed slightly from the script i had which was working, as ive been fiddling around with it to try and find the issue)

Answer (score 1):

see

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Answer (score 0):

Check your access token it may be expired, you need to have a valid access token with rights to post on wall, try getting the updated access token and try